# Using single criteria and SumIf with multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Found an easy work around to dynamically iterate down a column and add up values for a single criteria.  Looking to expand the formula to work with the same single criteria, but add two columns NOT adjacent to each other:

=SUMIF(A:A,A2,L:L)

Criteria in Column A, want to sum column L AND column S.  Criteria is a text field.

Comment: Use a `=SUMIFS` or `=SUMPRODUCT` then.

Comment: what column do you want to SUM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A2,L:L)+SUMIF(A:A,A2,S:S)
```

is the only way I know of achieving this without creating extra cells

You can also create a new column that is the sum of L and S and sum on this column

Comment: Well that was an embarrassingly simple solution, thanks so much WNG.   Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees...